# Select option value

Tags: php

I have a selection dropdown. Now what i want to accomplish is having a default first value (insted of an empty line in the pulldown menu).
The value needs to be "All manufacturers" and should be displayed always (like a placeholder.
If nothing is chosen, it will automatically search all the products of all manufacturers

```
<option <?php if(!isset($brand)) { echo 'selected="yes"' ; } ?> ></option>
<?php usort(
$manufacturers,
function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
)
?>
<?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
<?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id) {         ?>
<option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']; ?>"     selected="selected"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];     ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Jeeez code with a `<?php` tag on every line is almost impossible to read. How on earth will you manage to maintain this code?

Comment: It looks like you already know how to use `selected="selected"`.  Have you tried setting that on your default `<option/>` if there's no value in `$manufacturer_id`?  Or if you just put the default `<option/>` first then it should be selected by default when no selection is specified.  How specifically is your attempt not working?  What HTML does this generate and how do you want it to change?

Comment: I am guessing but maybe what you mean is `<option value"0" <?php if(!isset($brand)) { echo 'selected="yes"' ; } ?> >All Manufacturers</option>`

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @RiggsFolly   awesome, this is what i was missing (as i am not a php programmer, but understand how to read it). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think you want to do this

```
<option value"0" <?php if(!isset($brand)) { echo 'selected="yes"' ; } ?> >All Manufacturers</option>
```